# Unlock a Bitcoin-qt wallet

Tags: wallet

How do I unlock a bitcoin-qt wallet? I know my passphrase and all.
It says that my wallet is encrypted and locked for now so how do i unlock it?

Answer (score 4):

To unlock your wallet:

#### Option 1: Introduce password in prompt that opens when you send coins

#### Option 2: Console (Help > Debug window > Console)

Type the following:

```
walletpassphrase "passphrase" timeout
```

Where passphrase is your password and timeout is the number of seconds you want the wallet unlocked (i.e. 120 = 2 min). This is option is the only one when you want to do something that requires unlocking but you don't want to send coins (like dumping a private key) or when you plan to leave the wallet open and fear forgetting to lock it again.

Answer (score 2):

It unlocks when you need to spend.  If you try to send money to an address, it'll ask you for a password.  You don't need a password to receive bitcoins.