# Bitcoin core on macOS - shows "wallet is encrypted and currently locked"

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I downloaded the Bitcoin Core GUI wallet on my Mac. I then fully synced the node and imported my wallet's backup, which worked fine.

Now Bitcoin Core says, "wallet is encrypted and currently locked". I have the password for the wallet, but I'm not sure how to unlock the wallet. Is there a place to unlock the wallet?

Comment: I couldn't find that message in the source code, which website did you download it from?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick https://bitcoin.org/en/download

Comment: That v22 is out of date, the current version v25 is available at https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/.  See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101495/13866.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unlock a Bitcoin-qt wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/unlock-a-bitcoin-qt-wallet)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I got it working once I had updated it to the latest version. Thank you.